# Determine whether $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is surjective

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\setminus \{ 1\} $ be a function for   $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$.

I'm trying to prove that $f$ is not surjective (because WolframAlpha says that the function is not surjective). However, when I try to prove this by contradiction, I get that $f$ is surjective:

$f(x)=f\left(\frac{f(x)-1}{f(x)}\right)=\frac{1}{1-\frac{f(x)-1}{f(x)}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{f(x)}}=f(x)$

Which suggests that the function is surjective, but WolframAlpha disagrees. Where did I go wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first equality in your solution puzzles me. Where did it come from?

Comment: What is $f^{-1}(0)$?

Comment: How does f(x)=0?

Comment: @GitGud It comes from rearranging $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for x and plugging it into $f(x)$

Comment: @DanielFischer I see now, it's not surjective because $ \{ 1\}$ is not in the domain. Thanks :)

Comment: @aL_eX, No.  It's not surjective because $0$ is not in the range.